# New row in Django text field

Tags: python, html, django, row

In my Django app I have:

models.py

```
content_don = models.TextField()
```

I write content into that field and then save it with 'Submit'. Problem is, on my page I preview it with:

post.html

```
<p class="article-content mt-3 mb-1"><strong>Description: </strong></p>
<div class="media content-section mt-1  mb-1">
    <p class="lead">{{ post.content_don }}</p>
</div>
```

All content is in the same row. There are now rows which I typed in when I wrote text during form input. Why is that?

Comment: string it self don't have the concept of rows, to have multiple row you need a wysiwyg editor to save a formatted string, this django package support it https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor. For more packages that support wysiwyg input, you can take a look at https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML needs the newlines converted into markup, typically `<br>`. There's a Django builtin [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) to do this.

```
{{ post.content_don|linebreaks }}
```